# checkbox when unchecked, it should handle overwriting or deleting of previous saved file in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a checkbox in my visual studio project which saves the trace file in a particular location. To start the capture of trace file, there is another button for it. (Trace file contains information related to the device that is under the test). Now, When Save button(as in checkbox) is not clicked, during next start capture, the last or previous trace file has to be overwritten or deleted. I have to write a condition for overwriting or deleting of trace file.
I am new to visual studio so am finding it hard to handle this requirement. Can anyone please help me with this.

this is .xaml part:

```
<CheckBox Content="Save Traces :" x:Name=" CheckSave" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding SaveTraces,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="#673"/>
```

i need help for .cs part to handle the requirement.

Comment: Well, seemingly you have already bound your checkbox to the property `SaveTraces`. So the condition would be `if (SaveTraces) doWhateverWhenCheckBoxIsChecked(); else doWhatEverWhenCheckboxIsNotChecked();`

Comment: dont i need a boolean variable to save whatever has been executed in that method ?

Comment: Nobody knows. Because the only thing you revealed about your project is, that you have a checkbox. If you expect people to help you must add more information ..

Comment: its quite big, so i coudnt post it here.

Comment: the checkbox is bounded somewhere else and i have method in seperate class in which i have to write the condition about my requirements